# Kafka Streams: POJO serialize/deserialize backward compatibility

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Can the serialVersionUID be defined in the class that extends the Kafka interface Serializer/Deserializer (org.apache.kafka.common.serialization), similar to the one we implement with Serializable? Would we face exception -  NotSerializableException, during Java/Kafka upgrade?

For example, in KTable the key/value is serialized with a custom class object.  So, if we persisted some data and if any upgrade takes place for either Kafka OR Java OR both, will we be able to to read (deserialize) the key/value, that was persisted prior to the upgrade, without any backward compatibility constraints?

Reference:
[What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)

Comment: It's unclear to me, what the question is about. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Hi Matthias, please find additional detail above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write a custom Kafka `Serializer`/`Deserializer` there is no need to specify Java's `serialVersionUID`. You can still do it, but it would be unused.

The purpose of Java's `serialVersionUID` is to use Java's built in serialization mechanism. But this mechanism is not used when you implement a custom `Serializer`/`Deserializer` for Kafka.